# How to get the child's ID using DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$( document ).ready(function myFunct() {

    var platforms = "${platforms}";
    var platformList = platforms.split(",");
    var btn = new Array(platformList.length);
    var image_id = new Array(platformList.length);
    var img = new Array(platformList.length);

    for(i=0;i<platformList.length;i++)
    {
        image_id[i]=100*i-1 + "";
        console.log(image_id);
        btn[i]=document.createElement("button");
        img[i]=document.createElement("image");
        btn[i].appendChild(img[i]);  
        btn[i].appendChild(document.createTextNode(platformList[i]));
        document.body.appendChild(btn[i]);
       // document.body.appendChild(img[i]);
        btn[i].setAttribute("id",i+"");
        img[i].setAttribute("src","");
        img[i].setAttribute("id",image_id);
        console.log("button id is: "+i+" and image id is :"+image_id[i]);

        console.log("hiding");
        $("#"+i).hide();
    }
    var testId = "${testId}";
    console.log("hey");
    var is_loaded = false;
    var delay = 1;


function fetchFunct(){
        console.log("entered function");
        $.ajax
            ({
              type: "GET",
              url: "/content/mosaic/multi/preview/status/"+testId ,
              async: true,
              dataType : "json",
              success : function(response)
              {
                  console.log(response);
                  console.log(response.images);
                  if(response.status === false)
                  {
                  //something
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      for(i=0;i<platformList.length;i++)
                      {

                          $("#"+i).show();
                          console.log("image id is : "+image_id[i]);
                          console.log(platformList[i]);
                          console.log("Loading :"+i);
                          $("#"+i).click(function(){
                          console.log(this.id);
                          console.log("the first child is :"+this.NEED_CHILD'S_ID);
                          alert("you clicked the "+platformList[this.id]+" button");
                          $("#"+NEED_CHILD'S_ID).attr("src","http://" + response.images.platformList[this.id]);
                          })
                       }

                  }
              }
```

platformList contains = {android22 , android4 ..etc }
I am trying to dynamically create buttons according to the input platformList and on clicking the buttons i want to show the corresponding image . But I am facing two problems :

1. Retrieving the id of the child of a button (which is the image)
2. Getting an error if I try to change the source attribute to response.images.platformlist[this.id] , it accepts hardcoded stuff like images.android22 etc but I want to make it variable

Answer (score 0):

in the click-function of the button you could use:

```
$(this).find("img").attr("src","http://" + response.images.platformList[this.id]);
```

see: http://api.jquery.com/find/

I've created a JS-Fiddle for you to play around. You should reduce your example to a jsFiddle so people can help you: http://jsfiddle.net/cLK2z/

Comment: $(this).find("img[this.id]").attr("src","http://" + response.images.platformList[this.id]); On doing this I am still getting error : Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: img[this.id]

Comment: There is something wrong with images.platformList[this.id] .Also on replacing platformList[] with some hardcoded image name like android22 I am not getting any error but no image is loading

Comment: What does your response look like, What's the error-message you get in console? see my jsFiddle (I've edited my answer). Is your response.images undefined? Maybe "http://" is already contained in your responses URLs?

Comment: made a few changes . no more errors . only problem is i am not getting the images on the screen though i can see they have been received.

Comment: I think something is wrong with my childappend and body append part

Comment: will fiddle work here as i am taking inputs from outside  using <%@val testId:String %>
<%@val platforms:String %>

Comment: you should reduce the problem to the essential question(s) and post different questions for different problems with small fiddles to test. We're not going to develop your application in the comments of your post...